# Search in Phpmyadmin all Wordpress post that contains "fileadmin" and ".pdf"

Tags: mysql, regex, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I would like to search for all the wordpress posts that contains both these things: *fileadmin* and *.pdf*.

(Urls look like fileadmin/.../.../name.pdf)
How should I proceed with regular expression?

I got this actually:

```
SELECT * FROM `MYDATABASE`.`dv_posts` WHERE (CONVERT(`post_content` USING utf8) LIKE '%fileadmin%')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another LIKE statement? Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `MYDATABASE`.`dv_posts` WHERE (CONVERT(`post_content` USING utf8) LIKE '%fileadmin%' AND CONVERT(`post_content` USING utf8) LIKE '%.pdf%')
```

Comment: By the way I tried it and this also seems to work
SELECT *  FROM `Mydatabase`.`dv_posts` WHERE (CONVERT(`post_content` USING utf8) LIKE '%fileadmin%pdf%' )